# Windows 10 Mobile height of soft keyboard

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

Does anybody know how to move content of the page (maybe set relative margins or something like that) when soft keyboard is shown.

Here is the example page from my application.

[image: 1]

So I want when the user starts typing a phone number in the text box the bottom button will be shown above the soft keyboard. As a result I want something like that:

[image: 1]

P.S: Sorry about Russian language on the screens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's kind of tricky, but as I've tried should work. I've used *InputPane's* showing and hiding events to change the translate transform of the button. In page's constructor I've added such code:

```cs
Windows.UI.ViewManagement.InputPane.GetForCurrentView().Showing += (s, args) =>
{
    GeneralTransform gt = loginButton.TransformToVisual(this);
    Point buttonPoint = gt.TransformPoint(new Point(0, loginButton.RenderSize.Height - 1));
    var trans = new TranslateTransform { Y = -(buttonPoint.Y - args.OccludedRect.Top) };
    loginButton.RenderTransform = trans;
    args.EnsuredFocusedElementInView = true;
};

Windows.UI.ViewManagement.InputPane.GetForCurrentView().Hiding += (s, args) =>
{
    var trans = new TranslateTransform { Y = 0 };
    loginButton.RenderTransform = trans;
    args.EnsuredFocusedElementInView = false;
};
```

You only have to remember that *InputPane* is for the whole app - once you leave the page, you will probably have to unsubscribe from those events, otherwise you will likely get exceptions.

Comment: Hello again. Thanks a lot for your previous help, but can you explain me one more thing, please? After TranslateTransform, when the button is now above the keyboard I cannot touch it. The click event goes through the button. How Can I fix that?

Comment: @KonstantinChsherbakov I'm not sure about this and don't have much time now. I think better would be if you could ask another question on SO, maybe somebody will know the answer.